# ScrollViewer in datagrid doesn't work as attribute

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to add a simple vertical scrollbar but somehow first 2 options below dont work, only the 3rd one works. I want to know what are the differences.

option1: (as datagrid attribute)

```
  <StackPanel>       
      <Grid>
        <DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource Viewobj}"   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding myDatasource}" BorderThickness="2"/>
     </Grid>
```

Option2: wrapping around Grid

```
      <StackPanel>   
  <ScrollViewer>    
          <Grid>
            <DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource Viewobj}"   AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding myDatasource}" BorderThickness="2"/>
         </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>                  
  </StackPanel >
```

option 3: wrapping around stackpanel

```
<ScrollViewer>   
<StackPanel>   
           <Grid>
            <DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource Viewobj}"   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding myDatasource}" BorderThickness="2"/>
         </Grid>               
  </StackPanel >
  </ScrollViewer>
```

When I add all together, you can see how it looks like from inner one to outer one respectively.( 3rd working one is the outer one, on the most right)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your `Grid` a height, or change your `StackPanel` to something that limits the size of it's children, such as a `DockPanel` or `Grid`.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" Height="400" />
```

Or

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg" ... />
</Grid>
```

By default, a `StackPanel` allows its children to take up as much space as they need, resulting in the Grid being allowed as much vertical space as it wants and rendering at full height. By giving it a `Height`, you are limiting the space it is allowed to take up, which will make it show the ScrollBar.

The same problem occurs with your second block of code, however I would recommend against wrapping your `DataGrid` in a `ScrollViewer` if possible because it will cancel the DataGrid Virtualization, which could result in long load times and/or poor performance for a lot of records.